# Sometimes not able to login in on SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, user-accounts

I have one development environment which is having SharePoint 2013 installed. All the required permissions are there on site for users.

Sometimes when a user logs in to site it is working fine, but suddenly the site prompts for credentials and user is not able to login even after putting in correct credentials. Why is this happening? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issues as you described. We solved it by following this [solution](http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenh/archive/2013/04/30/intermittent-quot-http-403-forbidden-quot-error-while-trying-to-browse-to-a-sharepoint-web-app.aspx).

The solution is to ensure that the Authenticated Users or \Users group (which usually contains DOMAIN\Users group) has Read & Execute, List Folder Contents and Read permissions on the /BIN folder below C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories{Sitename80}. Follow the steps listed below to grant the required permissions:

- Open Windows Explorer and navigate to the /bin directory of your web application
- Right-click on the folder and click on Properties
- Go to Security tab and click on Edit
- Click on Add and add the local server group Authenticated Users or \Users (this usually contains DOMAIN\Users group).
- Select the Read & Execute, List Folder Contents and Read permissions (if you are planning to add Everyone to the /bin folder, grant Read permissions only)
- Click OK to apply the new settings

Comment: Hi Remko thanks for your reply, i did the things you have mentioned but still my sharepoint site suddenly asks for credentials and then i cannot login for few minutes